# Changing TFS Server Bound to MS Project 2010

Tags: tfs, ms-project, tfs-2010

Recently we upgraded our TFS server 2008 to 2010.
Now, we have got problems with MS Project 2010.

How can we change bound TFS Server to Ms Project 2010?

We also tried to delete VS Team System Do Not Edit lines at property pages of mpp file.
This caused more problems.

Comment: really? no one don't know how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this questions answer had been very easy.
After i installed Visual Studio 2010, MS Project Team menu was updated and i saw "Configure Server Connection" link.